# SQL Query + Google Geocode Response XML

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql

I have the XML response from the Google Geocoding API stored in a SQL Server XML column. Can someone help me with a query that will return all rows where the XML contains > 1 result?

e.g.

```
<GeocodeResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
  <result></result> <!-- more than one result is present -->
  <result></result>
  <result></result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

So something like this gives me the first result:

```
SELECT XmlResponse.query('/GeocodeResponse/result') FROM Locations
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [exist()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method of the XML data type to check if there exist a second `<result>` node.

```
select *
from Locations
where XmlResponse.exist('GeocodeResponse/result[2]') = 1
```

Test the query here. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/101340/xmlcolumn-exist